# Nine-patch image bad quality

Tags: android, nine-patch

in my android app I want to achieve this kind of effect

[image]

Thinking about different resolutions and densities I decided to create a nine-patch png file:

[image]

When I stretch it it looks quite fine:

[image]

But in the android simulator it is blurred

[image]

As you can see the quality is bad. Why? What do I have to do to achieve the quality from the first image?

Comment: Did you create one nine patch image per screen density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi)? It is necessary for your image to look fine on every device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should provide different 9-patches for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi screens. Then write in manifest file this tag:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Then android will take appropriate drawable and will not blur it.

Comment: I just created a tool that resizes nice patch nicely. Just drag n drop a .9.png file and it will create ldpi, mdpi, hdpi 9p from the xhdpi version : http://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/